# Show that $≺$ is a total ordering

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

Let $ℕ$ be the set of positive integers. Let $D(n)$ denotes the number of divisors of $n$.
We define this binary relation: $n≺m⇔n≤m$ and $D(n)≤D(m)$

where $≤$ is the usual ordering in $ℕ$.

Show that $≺$ is a total ordering and each positive integer appears only one time in the defined list of $≺$.

I am not able to show that this ordering hold trues for all positive integers.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch: I just I cannot show that this ordering hold trues for all positive integers.

Comment: If you failed to show that the ordering is total, how about you try to prove that it is not by finding two numbers which are not comparable by the ordering (one being larger than the other but having less divisors)?

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch: Yes, I v'e tried doing this, but I failed also.

Comment: @DER: Is $4\prec 5$? Is $5\prec 4$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: No. How I can modify the law to obtain a total ordering

Comment: @DER: I don't see any natural modification; are you trying to accomplish some particular goal here? If so, we probably need more background.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I want to create a total ordering for natural numbers.

Comment: @DER It is clear that you want to create a total ordering for natural numbers, but it is not clear why you don't want to take '$\leq$'. If your goal is to just create another total ordering, then you could look at $n \prec m \Leftrightarrow 1/n \leq 1/m$...

Comment: @GenericNickname: But the goal is to use the number of divisors of each number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given relation is not total, but you could use the following modification:

$$n \prec m \Leftrightarrow D(n) < D(m) \text{ or } (D(n) = D(m) \text{ and } n \leq m)$$

I think this should work out ok.